# Scroll summary page to bottom, if there are no issues with the question

Tags: feature-request, design, asking-questions, quality-filter

When I am done with a longer question, I have to scroll down "Ask question" page to the bottom, to hit "Review your question" button. When this is done, and my question is reviewed, I have to scroll down again, sometimes really long distance (if my question includes a lot of images) to the very bottom again to hit the "Publish" question. This is quite annoying.

Can we have any resolution for that? I.e.:

- move / copy "Post your question" button under "Step 2: Review your question" box,
- add functionality of auto-scrolling down the whole page to the "Post your question button" when there are no issues with the question ("Your question is ready to publish!" result) and only keep it to, if indeed there is something to be fixed,
- *any other option or idea*.

I know this is tiny and might be considered as my laziness, but I think this is still an UX issue.

Comment: Related: [Why do I have to click twice to submit a question when Stack Exchange's automated question review has no advice to show?](/q/347679/622284) and [When you get the “Your question is ready to publish”, allow submitting it from that modal instead of moving to the bottom of the page](/q/347503/622284)

Comment: @Spevacus The second one is not related, but an exact duplicate. Somehow this slipped my search results when I was doing research prior to asking this question. Thanks for bringing this up, closing my question.